# Getting form data and post it to URL

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Hi i am trying to get data from HTML [form](https://www.enatic.com/) ( you can get form from **Policy Generator** button) and post it to specific URL once user submit the form

The code that I wrote is there

```
<script>
function formJS() {
    var a = document.getElementById('Your-Name').value;
    var b = document.getElementById('Email').value;
    var c = document.getElementById('Company-Name-3').value;
    var d = document.getElementById('Industry').value;
    var e = document.getElementById('States').value;
    var f = document.getElementById('No-of-Employees').value;
    url = 'https://nik477984.typeform.com/to/DTAD7ZPz#company='+encodeURIComponent(c)'&size='+encodeURIComponent(f)'&state='+encodeURIComponent(e)'&name='+encodeURIComponent(a)'&email='+encodeURIComponent(b)'&industry='+encodeURIComponent(d);
    document.location.href = url;
}
</script>
```

Its getting the data but not submitting i guess can you check whats the issue .

Thanks !

Comment: What's HTTP method you want to use for the request sending? You should consider, `window.location.href` allows to send only GET-requests, while forms usualy are sending by POST method.

Comment: I basically need to pass these variables to that URL so i think i need POST-request . So how i can cope with this .Sorry I am new in JavaScript

Comment: To get helpfull answer you need to know [HTTP method](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) that is waited on target server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing several `+`.  You have to write this:

```js
encodeURIComponent(c) + '&size='
```

Not this:

```js
encodeURIComponent(c)'&size='
```

If you had just checked the console, it would have told you about the error and even what line it occurred in.

Comment: It concerns all fields of the data.

Comment: Yes, you need a `+` between every function call and string.  Don't test code without the browser console open, otherwise you will miss the helpful error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use JAVASCRIPT sessionStorage to pass JAVASCRIPT variables from one page to another like this..

```
var a=document.getElementById("name").value;
localStorage.setItem("name", a) ;
```

You have stored the value entered in that form in form of "name"..
So when you want to access the stored variable just use

```
var new=localStorage.getItem("name") ;
alert(new) ;
```